# Why does my thread execute seven times and not six like I think it should do?

Tags: java, multithreading

I´m doing a project and I have to use threads. I have done this thread "Hilo1" and I want it to do something a specific number of times.

```
class Hilo3 extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (activoHilo3) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(Prueba.this, "Hilo3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                if(contador1==5){
                                    
                                        activoHilo3=false;
                                    
                            }
                            contador1++;
                        }


                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want it to show the messaje "hilo3" everytime it is executed, but I have tried it and it does it seven times and not six like I want.
If I run the app, the message will be displayed seven times and not six and I don´t know why. Because when contador reaches 5, the thread variable "activoHilo3" is set to false so it shouldn´t be executed anymore, but however it is executed one more time.
Any idea why this happens?
Thank you.

Comment: Make a [mcve] please!

Comment: Where is `contador1` defined? Given that it isn't defined here, other code can interact with it, which is an easy explanation. If no other code interacts with it, why don't you define it within `run()` / at least within `Hilo3` as private field?

Comment: @rzwitserloot contador1 is defined as 0: contador1=0;  The problem is that when the program enters the if clause and activoHilo3 is set to false, the thread is executed one more time after that. And I don´t know why that happens because activoHilo3 is false now and it shouldn´t be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It runs seven times because the moment you set `activoHilo3` to false is to late to stop the seventh pass through the loop.

Lets start the description at the moment where the loop is running the sixth time: `Thread.sleep(5000)` finishes and `contador1` is 5.

The next action in your thread is to call `runOnUiThread(...)`. This call schedules the `Runnable` to run some time later and returns immediately. After that the code in your thread checks the condition of the `while` loop and finds `activoHilo3` to be still `true`, so it starts a seventh time into the while loop.

Then, some time later, the code in the `Runnable` is executed on the UI thread. This code triggers the display of the toast, checks the value of `contador1` and sets `activoHilo3` to `false`. But at this moment your thread is already in the seventh loop, executing the `Thread.sleep(5000)`.

---

To fix the problem I would move the loop condition out of the `Runnable` into the `while` loop:

```
class Hilo3 extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (activoHilo3) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Prueba.this, "Hilo3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (contador1 == 5) {
                activoHilo3 = false;
            }
            contador1++;
        }
    }
}
```

Or, since extending `Thread` is rarely the right choice:

```
class Hilo3 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (activoHilo3) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Prueba.this, "Hilo3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (contador1 == 5) {
                activoHilo3 = false;
            }
            contador1++;
        }
    }
}
```

Or, when using Java Language Level 8

```
class Hilo3 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (activoHilo3) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                runOnUiThread(() -> 
                    Toast.makeText(Prueba.this, "Hilo3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                );
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (contador1 == 5) {
                activoHilo3 = false;
            }
            contador1++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understand what happens. Is there a way to fix that? Is there a way to prevent the thread to be executed a seventh time? Because  I imagine there´s a way to prevent this from happening but I don´t know how it would be. And thank you again for the answer.

Comment: @LuisDaniels The simplest solution would be to move the counting from the `Runnable` into the loop in your thread so that the `Runnable` on calls `Toast.makeText()`

Comment: so you mean, moving contador1++; from where it is now to the while loop? Like this?: public void run() { contador++;
            while (activoHilo3) {
                try {

Answer (score 1):

Your code calls runOnUiThread, and just after this, it test the flag activoHilo3 in the loop.

But when it does this test on activoHilo3, the code inside runOnUiThread may not have been run yet.

Also: You have multiple threads accessing activoHilo3 at the same time, which is not really supported, and require some kind of locking(Or at least volatile).